# Finding Max Length via a loop

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

[image]

I have this following query that returns two columns table names and field names:
sample s sample record:  table ='TABLOCTYP' field name='TYPDES', The query returns records 206 rows. We are using SQL Server 2012.

```
 SELECT 
   CODFIC_0 AS 'Table',
   ATABZON.CODZONE_0 AS 'Field' 
   FROM LIVE.AMSKZON
          INNER JOIN LIVE.ATABZON ON AMSKZON.CODTYP_0 = ATABZON.CODTYP_0
 WHERE ATABZON.CODTYP_0 ='DES'
 AND CODMSK_0 IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY CODFIC_0, ATABZON.CODTYP_0
 ORDER BY 1
```

Image one is the results of my first query

I am looking to take these results and pass them via maybe table valued parameter maybe a loop. Something like whatis below for every row in my table.  I am not sure how to do the from peace or scan may table.

```
  DECLARE @table        nvarch(15)
  DECLARE @field        nvarch(25)

  sET @table = 'ABATABT'
  SET @field ='NOMABT'
  SELECT MAX(LEN(@field),
  FROM @table
```

My results will be max field length in the table and contents of field.
I am needing to know which records have a max length >12 so I can clean them up before importing into my new system. So I need the field contents displayed to know what I need to clean up.

I am getting Inccorrect Syntec near 'Group By'

```
 exec ('select  
'''+@tab_name+''','''+@col_name+''',max(len('+@col_name+')),'''+@col_name+''' 
from [xxxx].'+@tab_name+'''Group By'''+@col_name+'''Having 
max(len('+@col_name+'))>12''')

 set @counter -= 1
end
```

Comment: Its not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish. If you could add sample data and expected results please.

Comment: You can't pass column or table names as "at parameters", instead I think you need to use "dynamic sql". But what are your really trying to achieve? do you really care about the max(len()) of the data stored in those columns - or do you just need to know the maximum allowed length of those columns (which can be accessed using system tables and not needing dynamic sql)

Comment: I am trying to clean up data so I need to clean up ones that have a max lenght longer than12 from the list I supplied.

Comment: NEVER write a stored procedure that takes unsanitised free form text and executes it. At the VERY LEAST query the system tables to validate that the table and field name combination exist BEFORE building and executing your dynamic SQL. Unless of course you Want the widest open security back door that you could possibly code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL to get the details of the columns for each of the table_column pair from YourTable.

try the following

```
drop table if exists #temp
create table dbo.result_tab (TableName varchar(100), FieldName varchar(100), Max_Length int, Max_Value varchar(1000))
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)) rn into #temp from dbo.YourTable

declare @counter int = (select count(1) from #temp)
declare @tab_name varchar(100)
declare @col_name varchar(100)

while (@counter > 0)
begin
    set @tab_name = (select TableName from #temp where rn = @counter)
    set @col_name = (select FieldName from #temp where rn = @counter)

    print('insert into result_tab select '''+@tab_name+''','''+@col_name+''',max(len('+@col_name+')), null from dbo.'+@tab_name+'')
    exec ('insert into result_tab select '''+@tab_name+''','''+@col_name+''',max(len('+@col_name+')), null from dbo.'+@tab_name+'')
    print('update result_tab set Max_Value = (select top 1 '+@col_name+' from '+@tab_name+' where len('+@col_name+') = (select Max_Length from dbo.result_tab where TableName = '''+@tab_name+''' and FieldName = '''+@col_name+''')) where TableName = '''+@tab_name+''' and FieldName = '''+@col_name+'''')
    exec ('update result_tab set Max_Value = (select top 1 '+@col_name+' from '+@tab_name+' where len('+@col_name+') = (select Max_Length from dbo.result_tab where TableName = '''+@tab_name+''' and FieldName = '''+@col_name+''')) where TableName = '''+@tab_name+''' and FieldName = '''+@col_name+'''')

    set @counter -= 1
end

select * from result_tab
```

please see the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=32e6a81c25eb879a95824af7db6e2a78).
HTH.

Comment: what is the results_tab referencing?  Say invalid object.

Comment: exec ('select  
'''+@tab_name+''','''+@col_name+''',max(len('+@col_name+')),'''+@col_name+''' 
from [x3v7].[LIVE].'+@tab_name+'''Group By'''+@col_name+'''Having 
max(len('+@col_name+'))>12''')

 set @counter -= 1
end

Comment: @JohnF oh, sorry, I have added the structure for result_tab in my answer. Please print the line before executing it (you'll find the error), add extra spaces before and after each string in dynamic sql. you can directly query result_tab to find get the length and value of the columns.